# Changing from TextBox to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a custom Membership for my app, and it's pretty much the same as the generic one. Among other details what's different is how I pass values to my `Register` post method.

Until now I had username, password, firstName, ..., state, all as strings (there's more but irrelevant for the question) in my method parameters, like so:

```
public ActionResult Register(string userName, string password, string confirmPassword, string firstName, string lastName, string address, string city, string state, string zip)
```

The issue at hand is `State` parameter, now I want it to be passed from a dropdown not from a textbox as it was so far.

I've made a model for dropdown to be populated.

```
public class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

And added appropriate `SelectList` in my `Register View` method.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;

    return View();
}
```

Then I've altered the `Register` `View`, and made a dropdown instead of `Html.TextBoxFor` helper.

```
@Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateID, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

Note that, all these parameters excluding `username` and `password`, are saved in `User Profile` properties. This is how that's done in `Register` post method.

```
ProfileBase _userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);

_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", firstName);
_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", lastName);
_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Address", address);
_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("City", city);
_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("State", state);
_userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Zip", zip);

_userProfile.Save();
```

Lastly, the problem is that it doesn't get saved. The `State` property for that users `Profile` is empty.

I've tried several more ideas but nothing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown should have the same name as the parameter you want it to map to. It looks like it's id is **"StateID"**, but it should read **"state"** (as the name of the parameter).

So it should read:

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateID, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used a different name in the dropdown to the parameter that you are trying to map it too in the action.

If you make the two match then this should help solve your problem.

So you should change it to:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("State", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateID, new { @class = "ddl" })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks already solved with Marios help. +1 since this is correct too.

Comment: Should have written an answer first, but it's always good with some extra explanation =)